# Proving continuity for $f$ where $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq c\sqrt{|x-y|}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function for which there exists a constant $c >0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| \le c\sqrt{|x-y|} $for all $x, y \in\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: In fact $f$ is uniformly continuous

Comment: Corresponding to $\epsilon>0$ choose $0<\delta <\frac{\epsilon^2}{c^2}$ then if $|x-y|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|\le c\sqrt{|x-y|}<c\frac{\epsilon}{c}=\epsilon$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, if we have:

$$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq C |x-y|^{\alpha}$$

where $\alpha > 0$, $f$ will be continuous. These functions are called $\alpha$-Holder continuous functions and they are uniformly continuous. The reason is given $\epsilon >0$, set $$0<\delta<(\frac{\epsilon}{C})^{1/\alpha}$$
And

$$|x-y| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)| \leq C |x-y|^{\alpha} < \epsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*: Fix $\epsilon>0$.  Then, if $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ are such that $|x-y|<\delta$ (to be specified by you), we have
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\leq c\sqrt{|x-y|}<c\sqrt{\delta}.
$$

You need $c\sqrt{\delta}<\epsilon$. So, what should be your choice of $\delta$?

Comment: thank you! this really helped